# How to get a list of preferred languages on Linux?

Tags: linux, localization

Android, web browsers and Windows, for example, have an API that allows to get a list of preferred languages. Is there a similar thing on Linux (like Gnome API or KDE API)?

Comment: What do you mean? List of input sources? Which setting are you talking about?

Comment: @rustyx On Android, you can choose several languages that will be used for both inputs and for displaying content. Is there a similar one in Linux? It could be Gnome or KDE API.

Comment: Spoken/written languages, not programming languages, yes?

Comment: Yes, get the "hunam" languages from the program language :)

Answer (score 2):

For something basic and somewhat platform-independent, you could try fetching the C locale information. It is a POSIX standard to set basic locale information in certain environment variables, the most useful of which for you would likely be `$LANG`. If you're on a Linux system right now, try running `echo $LANG` in a shell.

POSIX also provides a `locale` command. If you run `locale` in a shell, it will output information about the currently selected locale. If you want a list of available locales, you can try `locale -a`. The man pages [locale(1p)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/locale.1p.html), [locale(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/locale.5.html), and [locale(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/locale.7.html) have more useful information about POSIX locales.

Comment: On Android, you can choose several languages that will be used for both inputs and for displaying content. Is there a similar one in Gnome or KDE API?